# Creating Search Function in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-applications

I am trying to make search function in my web application.

Basically, i have one `text box` and one `button`. 
Also i have `listbox` to render the search results.

I am using follwing query on access which is returning nothing.

```
SELECT [identifier] FROM [Category3]
WHERE [identifier] LIKE '%' + @name + '%';
```

The value for `@name` comes from the `text box`.

I am looking to search only one column of the table, so i will like to render the return results to the `list box`.

Do i need to use DataSet to store and render the results.

Any advice will be appreciated.

**CODE:**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchDB(TextBox1.Text);

        }



public DataSet searchDB(string identifier)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            // Create connection object
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT [identifier] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '% + @name + %'";

                OleDbCommand oleComm = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);
                oleComm.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.Char).Value = identifier;

                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Category3");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
            }
            finally
            {
                oleConn.Close();
            }
            if (dataSet.Tables.Count <= 0)
                return null;
            else
                return dataSet;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: well if name = help then `SELECT [identifier] FROM [Category3]
WHERE [identifier] LIKE '%' help '%';` see the misplaced quotes

Comment: which misplaced are you referring to.

Comment: Try  "SELECT [identifier] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '%+ @name + %'";

Comment: Doesn't work that way either..

Comment: If you run the query brings values?

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is here

```
WHERE [identifier] LIKE '%' + @name + '%';
```

it should be

```
WHERE [identifier] LIKE '% + @name + %';
```

shouldnt have single quotes around the % signs

Comment: +1 Dev N00B You r right, i have comment that but OP said that it does not working.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should try this

string sql = "SELECT [identifier] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '%' + '@name' + '%' ";